# Select Data From Solr Server in Java

Tags: java, apache, solr

I am working in a struts project and there I am using Solr Server as the database.

I need the Java codes and procedure to select, insert, update and delete.
Can any one help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solr is not a relational database, therefore there is no SQL or relational algebra.

To add/update/delete/query documents, use the [SolrJ library](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/Solrj). Here's a [quick tutorial](http://e-mats.org/2008/04/using-solrj-a-short-guide-to-getting-started-with-solrj/).